# ssh socks5 client via python does not work

Tags: python

I try to use ssh socks5 via python

I first test my ssh connection manually (I got the account from a free socks5 provider)

real username = user

real server ip = server

```
ssh -vvv -ND 5545 -p 443 user@server
[...]
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
server@server s password:
<I enter my password here>
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network   -> it works smoothly!
```

Now, I try the same thing with interactive python3:

centos 8 with Python 3.6.8

installed modules:

python3-pysocks.noarch

python38-pysocks.noarch

I followed the /usr/share/doc/python38-pysocks/README.md instructions doc.

```
python3
import socks
c = socks.socksocket() 
c.set_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "localhost", 5545, username="user", password="pass")
c.connect(("server",443))
```

I have got 2 errors when trying to connect with the above configuration:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/liConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] 
Connection refusedb/python3.6/site-packages/socks.py", line 832, in connect
super(socksocket, self).connect(proxy_addr)
debuConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refusedg1: Entering interactive session.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/socks.py", line 100, in wrapper
return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/socks.py", line 844, in connect
    raise ProxyConnectionError(msg, error)
socks.ProxyConnectionError: Error connecting to SOCKS5 proxy localhost:5545: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I have digged the web to find the solution but the only things I have found so far was related to http proxies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution here: https://pypi.org/project/pr0cks/

```
pr0CKS --proxy SOCKS5:127.0.1.1:5545
```